# Calculations based on values from the database in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, crud

I have got simple CRUD application in Spring MVC with fields: userName (String), height(float), weight(float), liverCoef(float). I need to do some math operations on 'liverCoef' (for examle: 2 * (liverCoef / 9) +7) and display results next to 'username' in JSP table. I can only do these math operations in the jsp code, but I know this is a bad practice. How can I do it in accordance with good practices?

Comment: Well, do them in the Java code instead.

Comment: it's not very bad practice but if you want a better way you can create a method in your java form then call it from jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create other property inside that class that you have those properties(username, height, weight and liverCoef) to obtain that calculation, for example:

```
public class Person {
 private String username;
 private float height, weight, liverCoef, someCalculation;

 //getters and setters
 public float getSomeCalculation() {
   return 2 * (liverCoef / 9) +7);
 }
}
```